# PHP function that generates categories menu slows the server. Please help to optimize it - maybe recusrsive function?

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have this function that generates products categories menu. It worked fine weeks ago when I had less categories but each time I add new category the page load time is getting higher. Here is the function:

```
function getProductCategorieshome(){
$query='select id, bg_category,url from products_categories 
where visible="1" and parent="0" group by bg_category order by bg_category ASC';    
$result=mysql_query($query) or die();    
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);    
if($num_rows){
echo '<ul id="mmenu" class="top-level">';
$htm='';
for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++){
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    //sub category    
$query="select id,bg_category,parent,url from products_categories 
where visible='1' and parent='".$row[0]."' group by bg_category order by bg_category ASC";
$result1=mysql_query($query) or die();
$num_rows1=mysql_num_rows($result1);
    if($num_rows1>0){
    $sub_htm='';
    for($j=0;$j<$num_rows1;$j++){
    $row1=mysql_fetch_row($result1);    

//here I check if we have products associated with the category so not showing empty categories    

$querys="select distinct pc.id, bg_category,url 
from products_categories pc, products_to_categories ptc, products p 
where pc.id IN(select id from products_categories where 
visible='1' and parent='".$row1[0]."' group by bg_category order by bg_category ASC) and     
pc.id=ptc.category_id and p.id=ptc.product_id and 
p.id not in (".$_SESSION['expired_products'].") 
group by bg_category order by bg_category ASC";
$result1s=mysql_query($querys) or die();    
$num_rows1s=mysql_num_rows($result1s);
if($num_rows1s>0){
$sub_sub_htm='';
for($k=0;$k<$num_rows1s;$k++){
$row1s=mysql_fetch_row($result1s);
$sub_sub_htm.='<li class="li5">'.$row1s[1].'</li>';
}
if(!empty($sub_sub_htm)) $sub_htm.='<li class="li2">'.$row1[1].'<ul class="sub-level">
'.$sub_sub_htm.'</ul></li>';
}else{  
$sub_htm.='<li>'.$row1[1].'</li>';
}   
}
if(!empty($sub_htm)){
$htm.='<li class="li2">'.$row[1].'<ul class="sublevel">'.$sub_htm.'</ul></li>';
}
}else{
$htm.='<li class="li1">'.$row[1].'</li>';
}
}   
    echo $htm;
echo '</ul>';
}
}
```

My products category table looks like:

```
#id    #bg_category    #parent    #url
1      phones           0         phones
2      smartphones      1         smartphones
3      Nokia            2         nokia
........... and so on
```

How this function can be optimized. If I dont call the function page loads on average 1 sec. After I load it the load time increase to 4,5 sec.. I believe that adding more categories will increase the load time problems..

Sorry if I could not format the code below better !

Comment: I would suggest that the delay comes from the inner sql statements being constructed and executed and then processed for every iteration of the outer loops - crazy. Adding more categories will slow this down further. It might be quicker to fetch the recordset into an array and then iterate through that.

Comment: @RamRaider, I removed the inner sql just to check if this is the reason but the result was even worse..

Comment: it's very hard to tell because of the lack of formatting but it looks like there are multiple nested loops - two nested nested loops within main loop is that correct? Ridiculous. I would suggest that you have a good look at what you are trying to achieve and try to code up the sql in an editor ( heidi ? ) because I think you are on the wrong track with this approach

Comment: yes, I can see that :)